# How to make numpy array slicing elements distinct?

Tags: numpy

I'm going to process a numpy array and make it the form I want.

Here is the source array:

```py
a = np.array([
  [0, 1],
  [0, 2],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 3],
  [2, 1]
])
```

The result array is like: the first column elements stay distinct, and the second column element is the average by the relevant first column element.

Explain in details:There are two `0`, three `1` and one `2` elements in the first column of `a` . The result `ret`'s first column has no-repeat elements `0/1/2`. At the same time, the second column element of `ret` gains the mean or median of `[1, 2]` when index is `0` in `a`, mean or median of `[1,2,3]` when index is `1` in `a`(forget the types of them).

Note that it's not sure whether the first or second column of `a` is regarded as the index sequence.

```py
ret = np.array([
  [0, 1.5],
  [1, 2.0],
  [2, 1.0]
])
```

Sorry I've got no clue. Thanks for answers.

Comment: It's difficult to answer without the code used to create `ret`, so could you edit your code and show a [minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the error? It is also a bit difficult to understand what you want, so could you post how you would like `ret` to be?

Comment: Thanks@user2653663  I try to make it clear: There are two `0`, three `1` and one `2` elements in the first column of `a` . The result `ret`'s first column has no-repeat elements `0/1/2`. At the same time, the second column element gains the mean or median of `[1, 2]` when index is `0` in `a`, mean or median of`[1,2,3]`when index is `1` in `a`(forget the types of them). Is there anyway to solve that with numpy slicing, or do I have to convert the 2D numpy array to list or set.

Comment: I would suggest that you edit your question with the extra details to make it easier for others to answer. Given that explaination, shouldn't `ret[1,1]` be `2.0` instead of `3.0`?

Comment: @user2653663 Thanks again for caring and correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution using only NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
  [0, 1],
  [0, 2],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 3],
  [2, 1]
])

group = a[:, 0]
values = a[:, 1]
# Take unique group ids
group_ids, group_idx, group_counts = np.unique(group, return_inverse=True,
                                               return_counts=True)
# Compute sum of group values
group_adds = np.zeros(len(group_ids))
np.add.at(group_adds, group_idx, values)
# Compute means
group_means = group_adds / group_counts
# Compose result
result = np.stack([group_ids, group_means], axis=1)
print(result)
# [[0.  1.5]
#  [1.  2. ]
#  [2.  1. ]]
```

Note that `result` is an array with float type. If you want to keep the group id as integer, you can either just keep `group_ids` and `group_means` as individual arrays or combine them into a [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html):

```
result_struct = np.empty(len(group_ids), dtype=[('id', 'i4'), ('mean', 'f8')])
result_struct['id'] = group_ids
result_struct['mean'] = group_means
print(result_struct)
# [(0, 1.5) (1, 2. ) (2, 1. )]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your array into a pandas dataframe and then use groupby.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [0, 1],
    [0, 2],
    [1, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [2, 1]])

a=pd.DataFrame(a)
a=a.groupby(0).mean()
```

Note that we group by "0" as we didn't assign any name to our variables and in your question you say that the first column is the one that you want to group upon.

Finally, if you want to transform back to a numpy array you can do:

```
a=a.values
```